# Is it possible to use Googles WaveNet Text-To-Speech model for the Actions-On-Google integration of a Dialogflow agent?

Tags: dialogflow-es, text-to-speech, actions-on-google, google-text-to-speech

Google Clouds [Text-To-Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/) has a WaveNet model whose output in my opinion sounds way better than the standard speech. This model can be used in Dialogflow agents (Settings > Speech > Text To Speech), which results in the generated speech being included in the [DetectIntentResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/DetectIntentResponse). However, I can find no way to use this speech with the Actions-On-Google integration, i.e. in an actual Google Assistant app. Have I overlooked this, or is this really not possible, and if so, does anyone know when they plan to enable this?

Answer (score -1):

In the Actions console, going to the **Invocation** page lets you select a TTS voice.

[image]

All of the voices can be demoed on the [Languages & Locales page](https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/languages-locales) of the docs, and the vast majority of them use WaveNet voices.

Comment: Hm, that's a bit confusing. I'm using the German Male-2 voice and was wondering yesterday why it suddenly sounded different. Seeing that is has indeed been updated explains that, but I feel like it has actually gotten worse. It seems that Dialogflow's de-DE-Male-2 voice is the de-DE-WaveNet-D voice of Cloud TTS. I would love to use de-DE-WaveNet-B and would assume that it is behind Dialogflow's de-DE-Male-1 (the only other male voice), but this option is greyed out in the AoG settings for me. Do you know what could be the reason for that?

Comment: According to an email we got from Google, Wavenet voices are being rolled out to Google Assistant from 4th March to the 11th March. We've seen (even more than usual) unpredictability in voice since receiving the email.

Comment: Ok, guess I'll have to wait and keep my fingers crossed:) Thank you!